# Getting the rate of a specific service - EasyPost

Tags: php, easypost

I currently have EasyPost creating a shipment.  When I create the shipment it provides me with all the available services and rates.

I would like to dynamically select service and only return that rate.

I originally would read through the array using the index number (I guess that how to describe it).

The problem with this is every time I create a new shipment the order of the rates array changes so what would have been $shipment->rates[0]['rate'] would be express and then the next time first class.

I want to create a shipment with "Express" and only return that rate.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
$name = $this->thiscustomer->cust_first . ' ' . $this->thiscustomer->cust_first;
$street_1 = $this->thiscustomer->street_1;
$street_2 = $this->thiscustomer->street_2;
$city = $this->thiscustomer->city;
$state = $this->thiscustomer->state;
$zip = $this->thiscustomer->zip;


$weight = $this->weight;
    $packaging = $this->packaging;
    $service = $this->service;
    $caddress = $this->consultant->address;
    $cstreet_1 = $this->consultant->street_1;
    $cstreet_2 = $this->consultant->street_2;
    $ccity = $this->consultant->city;
    $cstate = $this->consultant->state;
    $czip = $this->consultant->zip;
    $cname = $this->consultant->first_name . ' ' . $this->consultant->last_name;
    $cuser_id = $this->consultant->user_id;




require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/easypost.php');
\EasyPost\EasyPost::setApiKey('KUk4fZUI6YaYc1h0FiIXFw');


$shipment = \EasyPost\Shipment::create(array(
 'to_address' => array(
"name"    => $name,
"street1" => $street_1,
"street2" => $street_2,
"city"    => $city,
"state"   => $state,
"zip"     => $zip
 ),
 'from_address' => array(
"company" => $cname,
"street1" => $cstreet_1,
"street2" => $cstreet_2,
"city"    => $ccity,
"state"   => $cstate,
"zip"     => $czip
 ),
 'parcel' => array(
'weight' => $weight,
'predefined_package'=> $packaging
),
'rates' => array(
  'service' => $service
)

));

echo $shipment->rates[0]['rate']. '<br>';
```

Comment: You have exposed your EasyPost API key in the post above, please rotate your API key to ensure your account remains secure! You should also edit your post to remove the key and replace it with a placeholder or better, an env var.

Answer (score 3):

In EasyPost's [Getting Started Guide](https://www.easypost.com/getting-started/php.html#step4) there is an example of buying a specific carrier+rate:

```
$shipment->buy($shipment->lowest_rate(array('USPS'), array('Express')));
```

Comment: I don't want to buy it until I know what the rate is.

Comment: In that case, you will just have to do some array filtering. Other than selecting a carrier (which you can do using the carrier_accounts field) these details are business logic that EasyPost intentionally keeps out of its convenience methods so that you are determining exactly what you want. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

you can get different rates through below lines of code

```
if(!empty($shipment->rates))
{
$count = 0;
foreach($shipment->rates as $rate)
{ 
$serviceRates[$count] = [
'service' => $rate->service,
'carrier' => $rate->carrier,
'rate' => $rate->rate,
'currency' => $rate->currency,
'delivery_days' => $rate->delivery_days
];
$count++;
}
}
else
{
echo 'no result fond for given address';
}
      print_r($serviceRates);
```

Answer (score 0):

@KFunk is correct that EasyPost does not provide a native way to accomplish what you are asking since this use case is unique to you. The EasyPost client libraries provide all the functions needed to interact with the API; however, all of the business logic is left to the user.

If you want to create a shipment but only show a single rate to the user, you will need to filter out the other rates in your own application. To do this, you can follow the simple example here:

```php
<?php

\EasyPost\EasyPost::setApiKey($_ENV['EASYPOST_API_KEY']);

// Create your shipment, the response will contain all rates for all configured carriers
$shipment = \EasyPost\Shipment::create([
    'to_address' => [
        'name' => 'Dr. Steve Brule',
        'street1' => '179 N Harbor Dr',
        'city' => 'Redondo Beach',
        'state' => 'CA',
        'zip' => '90277',
        'country' => 'US',
        'phone' => '3331114444',
        'email' => 'dr_steve_brule@gmail.com'
    ],
    'from_address' => [
        'name' => 'EasyPost',
        'street1' => '417 Montgomery Street',
        'street2' => '5th Floor',
        'city' => 'San Francisco',
        'state' => 'CA',
        'zip' => '94104',
        'country' => 'US',
        'phone' => '3331114444',
        'email' => 'support@easypost.com'
    ],
    'parcel' => [
        'length' => 20.2,
        'width' => 10.9,
        'height' => 5,
        'weight' => 65.9
    ]
]);

$rates = $shipments->rates;

// Filter out all the rates that aren't the desired one, in this case - `Express`
$expressRate = null;
foreach ($rates as $rate) {
    if ($rate->service == "Express") {
        $expressRate = $rate;
        break;
    }
}

// Return $expressRate to your UI or do with it what you need
echo $expressRate;
```

Relying on array ordering is an antipattern that should be avoided. Array indices are never guaranteed to remain in the same order and do not have a strong bond to the data in question.

For further help with the EasyPost API specifically, you can reach out to our support team via support@easypost.com. Best of luck!